# Light wrap meshes for animation?

Tags: shaders, compositing-nodes, emission

I'm working on an animation where I have a moving object pass in front of a bright emissive billboard image and I'd like the light from the image to "spill", aka light wrap, around the object for a kind of glare effect. Can Blender do this?

I found several light wrap video tutorials for Blender, but they all apply the effect to static billboard images; I'm hoping there's a way to apply this to moving objects too. Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

[image: example]

Comment: What you're looking for is most often called "bloom".  In Cycles, this is done in compositing; in Eevee, this is done natively via render properties.  In neither case does it at all matter whether the objects move or not, because it is a post-process on the final rendered values.  Searching for "bloom" for either of your desired rendering engines will get you what you want.

Comment: @Nathan thank you for the reply. I've tried the Glare > Fog node in Cycles, and while it adds a beautiful bloom to the object when front-lit, there is no bloom when the light source is behind it, as in the screenshot where the red sun billboard and a sun lamp are the sole light sources. Even when the fog value is maxed out, there is no effect when backlit.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't understand the full problem.  You probably want to be using a volumetric object to get that kind of effect.  Make a cube surrounding the scene, with a principled volume shader plugged into volume output (and nothing plugged into surface output) and play with settings.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I played with your suggestion, as well as all the other compositing filters, but none come close to achieving the effect I want. If I were creating a static image then I'd do it post-render in Photoshop, but this is an animation.